# how to define the class order in spring integration test

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing

I have write some classes  for integration test

this is a parent class

```
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public abstract class ABC {
        
        @beforeAll
        // method 
}
```

in this abstract class only the pre req methods like db initialisation, and I am using this in my implementation classes

```
public class A extends ABC {

   @Test
   @Order(10)
   test1(){
    }



}

public class B extends ABC {
   @Test
   @Order(10)
   test2(){
    }
}
```

these two classes Class A and Class B extends abstract class ABC.
I want to run integration testing in order class A after  class B.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a custom class ordering in JUnit.
The configuration option to control the ordering is:

```
junit.jupiter.testclass.order.default=com.example.demo.CustomClassOrderer
```

Which you can use to provide custom [ClassOrderer](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.8.0/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/ClassOrderer.html).

ClassOrderer is responsible for ordering the classes encapsulated in the `ClassOrdererContext.getClassDescriptors()`.

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrdererContext;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class CustomClassOrdering implements ClassOrderer {
  @Override
  public void orderClasses(ClassOrdererContext classOrdererContext) {
    classOrdererContext.getClassDescriptors().sort(Comparator.comparingInt(classDescriptor ->
    {
      if (classDescriptor.getTestClass().getName().contains("A")) {
        return 0;
      } else return 1;
    }));
  }
}
```

You might need the dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But then you should be able to run the tests normally setting the property, for example:

```
mvn -Djunit.jupiter.testclass.order.default=com.example.demo.CustomClassOrdering test
```